# Any IDE or extension for helping debugging Rabbitmq?

Tags: debugging, rabbitmq, erlang

I am new to Erlang. I am working on investigating some details about how RabbitMQ handle messages. I want to create some breakpoints in its source code and watch the contexts. However, there seems to be no ideal IDE for Erlang OTP application, which can bring nice debugging experience just like IDEA for java.

Since the source code for RabbitMQ is managed by erlang.mk, I downloaded the source code, opened with VS Code + "Erlang LS" extension and could not find how to start debugging the project from the source code. Are there any suggestions for choosing IDE & extensions, or debugging the source code in a convenient way?

---

Tried:

VS Code + "Erlang LS" extension: can not find how to start debugging.

VS Code + "erlang" extension: it only supports projects managed by rebar/rebar3.

---

Expecting:

Convenient way to debug RabbitMQ from source code.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution myself.
You can enjoy debugging after the following steps:

1. Install "Erlang LS" extension in VS Code.
2. Uncomment "code_reload" setting in "erlang_ls.config" and input the right node name.
   For rabbitmq 3.11.5 on Mac OS 13, node name is "rabbit". If you are not sure about the node name, use

> epmd -names

to find the running nodes after you have launched rabbitMQ.

3. launch.json is like:

   {
   "version": "0.2.0",
   "configurations": [
   {
   "name": "Existing Erlang Node",
   "type": "erlang",
   "request": "attach",
   "projectnode": "rabbit",
   "cookie": "xxxxxxx",
   "timeout": 300,
   "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}"
   }
   ]
   }

"projectnode" should be the same with the node name used in the above step. "cookie" is the default Erlang node cookie.

4. Start rabbitmq with :

> bazel run -c dbg broker

5. Pressed "F5", and set breakpoints as you like. Rabbitmq are free to be debugged now.
   [image]