# Is there any additional step I need in order to debug RabbitMQ locally using VsCode and Erlang LS extension?

Tags: debugging, rabbitmq, erlang, vscode-debugger, erlang-otp

While trying to debug RabbitMQ locally I stumbled upon [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74898825/any-ide-or-extension-for-helping-debugging-rabbitmq) StackOverflow question. I tried following the exact same steps but unfortunately I couldnt make the breakpoint to work.

I noticed the ADP Server returned back to me `module not available (no_src) in the debugged node, reset the breakpoint when the module is availalbe` .

Cloning repo, installing RabbitMQ w/ `bazel sync` and `bazel run -c dbg broker`, configuring the launch.json and the extension . Unfortunately it seems like the ADP server is not finding the module

I also tried the above steps using Bazel and Make.

Is there any option I am missing?